# HTTP Error 500 when running php scripts

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I am running a PHP page and as soon as I introduce calls like this: $_GET('') then everything goes wrong and I get an error 500.

This code goes not work:

```
    echo $_GET('username');
    echo $_GET('password');

?>
```

This code does:

```
<?php

    phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: `$_GET` is not a function, it's an array. Back to the beginners manual you.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
echo "Username: ".$_GET['username']."<br />Password: ".$_GET['password'];
```

Since $_GET is a array and not a function, you need to use [square brackets] instead of (normal brackets) to retrieve the data out of a array.

Answer (score 1):

The above code has syntax errors - you need to use square brackets.

The web server's error logs will show you those errors if you have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what the problem is you need to turn on php error reporting. You do this by running this the first thing you do in your php-file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

`E_ALL` means the interpreter will show you errors, warnings and notices. After that, everything will be pretty obvious since php will tell you what went wrong.